# Statsmodels.api Logit model error ValueError: endog must be in the unit interval

Tags: python, python-2.7, statsmodels

I know what the error means -I double-checked and my Y variable data is definitely within [0,1] with:

```
Y.max() = 1
Y.min() = 0.7333333
dtype(Y) is float64
```

I am reading in data using pandas. This is the first time I am using statsmodels.api package. Any ideas of what else I should check for this error

Comment: Please add the full traceback so we see where it raises the exception.

Comment: Stupid rookie mistake - it did not like NaNs

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
In a logistic regression you need a dichotomy variable, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression, either 0 or 1.The minimum should be 0, otherwise you do not have categories you have a continuous variables and maybe you want to use a linear regression instead.

Comment: statsmodels allows endog to be continuous in [0, 1] interval for Logit and other binary models. We can use it with proportions or as a quasi likelihood model.